# SQLite3:Busy exception with Capybara/Poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, capybara, poltergeist

So im running SQLite and attempting to use fixtures to load in the proper data to display and test through the browser with capybara.

My test suite uses a Minitest w/Capybara and Poltergeist for the driver. the relevant portion of my `test_helper.rb` file looks like so:

```
require "minitest/reporters"
reporters = []
reporters << Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new
Minitest::Reporters.use! reporters, ENV, Minitest.backtrace_filter

require "minitest/rails/capybara"
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :js_errors => false)
end
Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

However I have a simple test that stubs a User access level login for the web application this is running on, and then simply visits the route.

However it's failing at what seems to be the "User Access Stubbing" method that im using. Which looks like `Core::User.any_instance.stubs(etc...)` which is just returning a user model.

Anyways the exact error I get is:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:         ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: commit transaction
```

Since im using fixtures would this maybe be a DB cleaner issue(Im not using it right now as im only using pre-created fixtures currently) I've never used DB cleaner with minitest as im only familiar with using it with rspec and factory girl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that another DB connection already has sqlite open for writing (it can handle multiple readers but only one writer at a time).  You don't show your actual test or your stub so it's impossible to say specifically where your issue is, but odds are you've made a request and then are running some other database access while it's occurring (for instance have you preloaded the object the stub returns, or does it get loaded when the stub is executed?).

If your app doesn't use sqlite as it's database then swap over to testing on the DB the app will use in production.  Additionally, stubbing is an anti-pattern in feature tests, you should just be creating proper records, and dealing with them.

Comment: I wish I could post the code, but since it's work code...I can't really. Thing is though the test is literally just opening a page and loading a user, which another test does successfully. However the other test just used minitest and the User-Agent,'Ruby' page.driver with capybara. Whereas I am using poltergeist with capybara.

Comment: @msmith1114  I don't understand what you mean by 'page.driver with capybara', if you mean it uses the racktest driver, that's a HUGE difference since it all runs in a single thread synchronously - hence only one DB connection.  When using poltergeist there are at least 2 threads (tests, app) and potentially more, can have multiple requests when the page loads and multiple DB connections.  If your app doesn't actually use sqlite in production swap to testing with whatever you use in production, you'll have a much easier time.

Comment: Problem is our production DB is a VERY old SQL-Server version that DB Cleaner won't work with, so going back to a clean slate each time is basically impossible. Is there any way around this sqlite issue? or maybe I just need to stick with non-browser based tests for now. and the driver it says it uses (someone else wrote this remember) is set as: `page.driver.header('User-Agent', 'Ruby')` which im guessing means it uses the rack driver

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean it's using the rack driver, that just means a header is being set for the next request, however it could imply racktest (both racktest and capybara-webkit drivers have `header` methods).  You should be able to work around the sqlite issue (assuming your app isn't making requests back into itself) by doing no direct DB access from the test thread once you've started visiting a page (which is generally good practice anyway), thereby insuring only the app under test is accessing the DB.